# How to pull certain data from a meta_value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a table inside wordpress which is `wp_usermeta` with the `meta_key` filed and a value called `wp_s2member_custom_fields` which holds a bunch of concatenated values like below.

How can I extract the data next to `monthly_uniques` inside this value?

```
a:12:{
s:7:"country";
s:2:"CA";
s:4:"city";
s:8:"Brampton";
s:5:"state";
s:7:"Ontario";
s:8:"zip_code";
s:6:"L6T4E7";
s:3:"age";
s:13:"25–34 years";
s:8:"blog_url";
s:22:"http://www.blog.com";
s:16:"blog_description";
s:106:"A blog about blogging";
s:15:"monthly_uniques";
s:4:"1000";
s:13:"facebook_page";
s:55:"http://www.facebook.com/myfacebookpage";
s:14:"facebook_likes";
s:3:"128";
s:15:"twitter_account";
s:31:"http://twitter.com/mytwitterpage";
s:17:"twitter_followers";
s:3:"392";}
```

*In actual fact al these values are on one line, put them on separate lines for clarity*

I need to pull this data in different ways to show reports.  What do I add the below statement to pull `montly_uniques`, city, zip_code, etc?

Answer (score 2):

When Wordpress enters an array into its database, it does something called Serializing, where it turns an array into the format of the string you supplied. To reverse this process and get back the same array, you simply need to run that string above through PHP's built-in [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function, which will return an associative array in the manner you mentioned above.

So something like this:

```
$string = 'a:12:{s:7:"country";s:2:"CA";s:4:"city";s:8:"Brampton";s:5:"state";s:7:"Ontario";s:8:"zip_code";s:6:"L6T4E7";s:3:"age";s:13:"25–34 years";s:8:"blog_url";s:22:"http://www.blog.com";s:16:"blog_description";s:106:"A blog about blogging";s:15:"monthly_uniques";s:4:"1000";s:13:"facebook_page";s:55:"http://www.facebook.com/myfacebookpage";s:14:"facebook_likes";s:3:"128";s:15:"twitter_account";s:31:"http://twitter.com/mytwitterpage";s:17:"twitter_followers";s:3:"392";}';

$array = unserialize($string);

$array['monthly_uniques']; //This will give you the monthly_uniques field.
```

Comment: How would I just pull this out in phpmyadmin?

Comment: @user, that's hard work, word_press is using a php function which has no equivalent in MySQL.

Comment: Problem is that I have 4500 of these in the table, and need to pull them and sort.

Comment: Well I know it's not elegant or efficient, but if you're not doing this often, it might be best just to pull them out into PHP, sort them, and then update the ordering.

Comment: Otherwise, as Johan said, this isn't an easy task using MySQL alone.

Comment: That sucks.  How does wordpress pull all this data into users then?